# Openshift vs localhost errors and error handling

Tags: python-2.7, flask, openshift

I can run the code below both locally and on openshift with success, but with very different results.  When I load '/' in both browsers I see that the code is working.

When I load '/main' in the browser it works locally, and it throws a 500 error(with no debug information) in openshift.

when I load '/error' in the browser I get debug information locally, and just 500 again in openshift.

How can I see debug information instead of a useless error message on openshift?

```
import watercore
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return '404'

@app.errorhandler(500)
def errorhandle(e):
return '500'

@app.route('/error')
'force a 500 error'
def testerrors(e):
    return watercore.thisdefinitiondoesntexist()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'working'

@app.route('/main')
def mainpage():
    return watercore.listall()

@app.route('/site/<sitename>')
def site(sitename):
    if watercore.listall(sitename) == True:
        return sitename

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Comment: How have you deployed on openshift? Did you follow [this](https://developers.openshift.com/en/python-flask.html)?

Comment: Yes I have deployed.  No I uploaded the example found here https://github.com/openshift/flask-example and modified it.

Answer (score 0):

Openshift probably runs your app using `wsgi`, so your `main` is never run. To enable debug set the it outside `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = True
    return app

app = create_app()
```

Note that you should never do this for an actual production app.

Comment: I pulled the app.debug = true up a couple lines, and got '500' as a response to the error. I then commented out my 500 code error handler and im back to a useless internal server error message.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the flask quickstart:

```
Attention

Even though the interactive debugger does not work in forking
environments (which makes it nearly impossible to use on production 
servers)
```

Which leads me to believe that the debugger will not work on openshift at all.

I've already switched to django!